# Flask App with Gunicorn in production giving Error: socket hang up

Tags: python, docker, api, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask app running as a Docker container using Gunicorn on a Paperspace server -

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
COPY . /backend
WORKDIR /backend
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD gunicorn --timeout 10000 --workers 4 --log-level debug --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app
```

**app.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from flask import Flask, request

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/uploads'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
           
@app.route('/upload_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    return "it works fine"
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from api import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I run it using

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8000:8000 myFlaskApp:1.28
```

On firing the API (/upload_file) from Postman, I'm getting

> ```
> Error: socket hang up
> ```

But, this API works fine on localhost (http://0.0.0.0:8000)

Comment: I was not able to recreate your issue using the above code snippets.  There are a few things that kept the docker container from building in the first place (the api folder didn't exist so I removed from api; the wsgi file is redundant so I removed it and put the if main check at the bottom of the app.py; changed the docker CMD to load the app from app:app).

When I resolved those issues then the application ran as expected.  I suspect that this is a simplification of a larger project and the actual issue is not represented in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the gunicorn server on it's own first in the terminal(without docker)

```
gunicorn -w xx -t xx -b 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:app
```

If gunicorn runs fine then its something wrong with the dockerfile. I think you should make ENTRYPOINT as gunicorn and then in CMD specify the params.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn"]
CMD ["-w", "4", "-t", "10000", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "wsgi:app"]
```